# multiple webbrowser navigation freeze problem

Tags: .net, vb.net, browser, webbrowser-control

I have problem with multiple webbrowsers on form so i created simple form with 10 browsers in it and 1 button:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/8a234c57-0872-469d-9b34-c89c54d3bed1")
WebBrowser2.Navigate("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(VS.95).aspx")
WebBrowser3.Navigate("http://www.thirdage.com/news/fran-crippen-dies-open-water-swimming-race_10-23-2010")
WebBrowser4.Navigate("http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052702303299304575569821760465604.html")
WebBrowser5.Navigate("http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2010/10/week-in-apple-small-laptop-edition.ars")
WebBrowser6.Navigate("http://www.pcworld.com/article/208658/verizon_iphone_rumor_wont_die.html")
WebBrowser7.Navigate("http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9192578/Facebook_others_move_to_boost_social_net_innovation")
WebBrowser8.Navigate("http://www.escapistmagazine.com/news/view/104656-BlizzCon-2010-Diablo-III-Wont-Be-an-E-Sport")
WebBrowser9.Navigate("http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/208642/first_look_imovie_11.html")
WebBrowser10.Navigate("http://www.latimes.com/news/nationworld/nation/la-na-turtles-20101023,0,7112487.story?track=rss")

Application.DoEvents() End Sub
```

When I click button and try to drag form1 everything is none or slow responding.

I see web site loading in browsers but nothing is responding on screen until loading of pages is finished. In the meantime my processor it goes to 90-100%

I tested exe on my laptop and is working same.

Is there any help against this or you are limited to 1 browser window??

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowser control uses IE as the rendering engine.
IE can be slow.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: Page loading speed is working fine, its just whole app get frozen or slow responding while loading pages in webbrowser's. I have also try Skybound.Gecko as webbrowser and i got same freezing results until pages are loaded completely.

Comment: That's because IE uses lots of CPU power to load pages.  This is exacerbated  by Flash ads on most of your pages.

Comment: ok, ill try on clean machine without flash, but why then i get same results with Skybound.Gecko browser. I'm trying to make app that will collect info from pages and its requires JS. That is why i try to use multiple webbrowsers.

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowser and the application are in the same process so when the WebBrowser is busy, your app isn't able to respond to mouse clicks.  See if you can use background threads.